# required formula for copying data between excels

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy the model codes from workbook1 to workbook2. When i type the model codes in workbook1, it should automatically be copied into workbook2. Please assist how can i get this done.

Comment: Use `Worksheet_Change` event. Search the web something like "excel vba on cell change" and "excel vba copy range to another sheet" or similar. Otherwise, show your code so somebody here can help you.

Comment: Below is the code I have used:Sub copying()
Workbooks("Prod").Activate
Range("A:B").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks("newexcel").Activate
Range("A1").PasteSpecial
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

If your destination workbook is already open the following should work. You should define the worksheet where data is copied to (here "Sheet1").

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Destination As Range

    Set Destination = Workbooks("newexcel.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Target.Address)
    Destination.Value = Target

End Sub
```